# Laravel insert diff between two times on model save

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a Laravel project but I have an issue.

I'm trying to save the difference between 2 timestamps to the database before I save the model:

My table:

```
  $table->increments('id');
    $table->time('from');
    $table->time('to');
    $table->time('diff');
```

So.. before inserting, calculate the difference between these two times and insert this on the same time.

Is this possible and can anyone help me?

Thankyou,

Comment: Do you mean difference in days or years or seconds?

Comment: Difference in hours and minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into saving() or updating() or creating()

so in your model add one of the above depending on which one you want to hook (I think saving() if I understand you correctly) and implement sth like the following:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::saving(
        function ($table) {
            $table->diff = strtotime($table->to) - strtotime($table->from);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank u!, to save the correct diff I did: $table->diff = gmdate('H:i:s', (strtotime($table->to) - strtotime($table->from)));

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the different between to and from in seconds:

```
$row = TableModel::find(123);

$diff = strtotime($row->to) - strtotime($row->from);
$row->diff = $diff;
$row->save();
```

Comment: Oke, but how can I do that everytime before saving the model ?